# Распознавание текста при произвольном расположении

Tags: c#, tesseract

Для распознавания текста использую Tesseract - https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract
Есть несколько вопросов:

1. Если текст достаточно мелок по сравнению с изображением, то распознать текст не удаётся вообще. Т.е. необходимо выделить конкретный участок с текстом. Есть ли другой способ решить эту проблему?
2. В обрабатываемых мной изображениях текст располагается произвольным образом, т.е. указать область с текстом заранее нельзя. Есть ли способ решения этой проблемы?

Comment: [Оно?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13637953/12888024) [Или вот](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)

Comment: @aepot, к сожалению,первая ссылка ни о чём =)) 2-ю видел, но так же не сказано ничего о произвольном расположении текста.

Comment: Возможно, необходимо сказать, что размер текста относительно небольшой